# People picker not working after machine rename Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, people-picker, synchronisation, rename

Silly me forgot to rename my foundations 2010 test server's machine name prior to installing SharePoint. I used STSAdmin to perform a server-rename after changing the machine name, but now local users are not appearing in the people picker any more. I.E. I cannot add local users into the site collection despite them having an account on the server.

The site, central admin, IIS, the content database are all housed on the same server. There's no replication concern here... Just need to "point" the people picker back to local users after the rename... Seems easy enough but I can't find the setting that needs to be changed.

**EDIT** - Plot thickens... If I simply enter a username into the permissions listing (I.E. don't even use the people picker) it resolves the user on the local machine... But when I try to search for them, they do not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, in my context, was that I needed to make my server a domain controller or add it to a domain. For some reason setting the "People and Groups" search to look at the local computer seems to be an impossibility. Falak's suggested answer *is* correct if the server hasn't been renamed; however if the server is a local system and not a domain controller then the local accounts won't show up anyway.

So that's that!! Upvoted the other suggested answer as it will probably prove to be helpful to someone else. (Thanks Falak!)

Answer (score 2):

1. Rename the server at the operating system level by using the System Properties dialog box in Control Panel.
2. Restart Server
3. Change or create SQL alias (If no ALIAS, create one to point to the old servername so it finds the SQL Server that is on the same server, stand-alone installation.) using cliconfg
4. Restart the server
5. Run PowerShell-command to rename SharePoint internally: (Powershell for SharePoint)

   *Rename-SPServer -Identity "OriginalServerName" -Name "NewServerName"*
6. Restart server
7. Update Web site mappings as needed to ensure continued access to all sites.
   IIS Bindings and Alternate Access Mappings in Central Administration

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I get this warning message `Rename-SPServer : The Server SERVERNAME could not be found in the farm. This operation is only valid fo servers that are joined to the farm.` I changed the servername using stsadm yesterday; it's simply that I can't see local users and groups anymore. Also the old server name still exists as a prefix for the users that were already granted access into the site. I think I'm going to have to rebuild, unfortunately.

Comment: It's possible that I am simply not understanding how SharePoint gathers users from Local Users and Groups. Is a local user even available in search before they have been added into the site? Would I have to set up a local instance of Active Directory and turn my SP server into a domain controller as well in order for search to allow me to peer into the AD listing?